# Is there a way to parse JSON and get request for this link with Python

Tags: python

```
resp= requests.get("https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/options/ivr")
resp_dict = json.loads(resp.text)
print(resp_dict)
```

Code returns this error :

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 1 resp= requests.get("https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/options/ivr")
> ----> 2 resp_dict = json.loads(resp.text)
> 3 print(resp_dict)
>
> /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/**init**.py in loads(s, cls,
> object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant,
> object_pairs_hook, **kw)
> 355             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
> 356             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
> --> 357         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
> 358     if cls is None:
> 359         cls = JSONDecoder
>
> /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
> 335
> 336         """
> --> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
> 338         end = _w(s, end).end()
> 339         if end != len(s):
>
> /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s,
> idx)
> 353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
> 354         except StopIteration as err:
> --> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
> 356         return obj, end
>
> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Help.. what am i doing wrong?
I expect to see a json dictionary on my jupyter notebook with a get request, then to parse the data with keys, but instead, the code outputs an error.

Comment: What don't you just try `.json()`?

Comment: @Xitiz I believe he is following a guide of sorts, and hasn't ventured in to trying his own ideas yet.

Comment: request is failing your code is getting response `'Forbidden'`. `print(resp.status_code)` is giving `403`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `resp` you're getting `403` which means yahoo is restricting your access.

Adding a user-agent is enough for the request to be completed successfully.

```
>>> headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"}

>>> resp = requests.get("https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/options/ivr", headers=headers)

>>> resp
<Response [200]>
```